# Campaign members auto-added to the campaign?

Tags: campaign, campaign-member

If I create a SFDC campaign and add members using a sfdc report (report type is "Contacts & Accounts") today.

Will the members to this campaign automatically get added based on the sfdc report filter criteria or do I need to apply any settings for members to get added automatically?

Thanks.

Comment: Adding via report is a one-time action. To add new members, you have to keep rerunning the report or look for a more automated alternative.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply @identigral. I've used process builder to auto-add the members based on the criteria (in my case when contact title contains "Research Scientist". So I've two questions - (1) typically when will the contact get added to the campaign or when does process builder executes? (2) Also, I've seen scenario where the SFDC report shows less number of records then the number of campaign members. Any idea, what could be the reason?

Comment: 1) It executes when the trigger inside the process fires. Take a look at [Process Builder](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/business_process_automation/process_builder) trailhead. 2) No idea. Worth a new question if you can gather all the relevant details (see [How to Ask](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask))